# Is SQLite in immutable mode safe on non read-only media?

Tags: sqlite

In an application that ships with a read-only SQLite database, I've found that opening the database as immutable radically improves query performance. However the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) says this (emphasis mine):

> The immutable parameter is a boolean query parameter that indicates that the database file is **stored on read-only media**. When immutable is set, SQLite assumes that the database file **cannot be changed**, even by a process with higher privilege, and so the database is opened read-only and all locking and change detection is disabled.

This is tripping me up a bit because the media (Windows Program Files) is not read-only and it can be changed, but the expectation is that it won't change. The application itself does not alter the database. A user *could* alter the databases using external tools (or just open it in Notepad and corrupt it) but we would call that user error and tell them not to do that.

My concern is that this part of the documentation might be hinting at some other process I'm not aware of (like maybe Windows periodically doing something that might result in the database file changing in some way).

**If the application itself does not alter the database, and the user doesn't either, and there isn't some other malicious or poorly-coded program on the computer that might be touching files that don't belong to it, is it reasonably safe to open a SQLite database as immutable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimentally, the answer appears to be yes, it is safe. I made this change and have not observed any problems with it.